# How to exclude subscriber from the list in wordpress

Tags: user-roles

Some what i have this code working perfectly, the problem is not excluding subscriber from the list, can somebody help me to exclude subscriber from the list.. thx

```
<?php 
$number   = 10;
$paged    = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$offset   = ($paged - 1) * $number;
$users    = get_users();
$query    = get_users('&offset='.$offset.'&number='.$number);
$total_users = count($users);
$total_query = count($query);
$total_pages = intval($total_users / $number) + 1;
echo '<ul id="list-mitra">';
foreach($query as $q) { ?>
  <li class="bullet-arrow">
        <a href="#mitra<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $q->ID);?>">
          <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID);?>
        </a>
  </li>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[lightbox id="mitra' . get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $q->ID) . '" width="600px" padding="20px"]
<p>Nama: '.get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID).'</p>
<p>Nama Panggilan</p>
<p>Alamat</p>
<p>No Handphone</p>
<p>Upline</p>
<p>Tim</p>
<p>Leader Tim</p>
[/lightbox]'); ?>

<?php } 
echo '</ul>'; ?>
```

Comment: try and use the parameter `'role__not_in'` see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/

Comment: yesssss.... thankyou so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working code ..thx @michael

```
<?php 
$number   = 10;
$paged    = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$offset   = ($paged - 1) * $number;
$users    = get_users();
$query    = get_users('&offset='.$offset.'&number='.$number.'&role__not_in='.subscriber);
$total_users = count($users);
$total_query = count($query);
$total_pages = intval($total_users / $number) + 1;
echo '<ul id="list-mitra">';
foreach($query as $q) { ?>
  <li class="bullet-arrow">
        <a href="#mitra<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $q->ID);?>">
          <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID);?>
        </a>
  </li>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[lightbox id="mitra' . get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $q->ID) . '" width="600px" padding="20px"]
<p>Nama: '.get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID).'</p>
<p>Nama Panggilan</p>
<p>Alamat</p>
<p>No Handphone</p>
<p>Upline</p>
<p>Tim</p>
<p>Leader Tim</p>
[/lightbox]'); ?>

<?php } 
echo '</ul>'; ?>
```